# Cannot add background image to my <div>

Tags: html, css, background

I have a div with more buttons and I cannot add an image to it.

**Html:**

```
<div class="menu_border" style="height: 460px; width: 290px;">

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu_border {
     float: left;
     border: 5px groove;
     margin-left: 70px;
     text-align: center;
     background-image:url('images\generale\bkgmenu.jpg');
}
```

My `css` and source codes are in the main folder. There is the folder *images->generale* and the images. I've tested the path, is correct. I've tried to add the image as normal `<img>` and it worked.

It does not work as background.

Comment: Its working for me. can you please add fiddle

Comment: Code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/g5vkgucf/  Maybe the image URL is wrong?  Check the network tab in your browser's debugging tools to see what the request was.

Comment: I think path should be like `background-image:url('..\images\generale\bkgmenu.jpg'); ` in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ur code needs to change like this

```
background-image:url('images\generale\bkgmenu.jpg');
```

to

```
background-image:url('images/generale/bkgmenu.jpg');
```

image will taken this format

Comment: Ty man...I did not know that in css you must use /. I've been working on Windows, that's why I've been using \