# cannot add background image css

Tags: html, css

I followed this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on7p8oqfv80

I cannot seem to add background image to a class. This image link does work, I have opened in browser and I have also previously added it using "img src=", directly into the html. It works.

I know the stylesheet is being linked properly, because the style of the text changes.

I have tried adding a width, using single quotes instead of double quotes, tried using background-image instead of background. I have tried using a local image and yes I am on Linux and yes I have chmod 777 on all files in that directory, just to be sure. I have tried  all of the different solutions offered across these following links:

[Cannot add background image to my <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993327/cannot-add-background-image-to-my-div)

[How to add background image in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170310/how-to-add-background-image-in-css)

[Cannot add background image to my <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993327/cannot-add-background-image-to-my-div)

Tried this on Firefox, Chrome and IE across Linux, Windows and Mac.

Here is the code

```js
var errorCallback = function(e) {
  console.log('Reeeeejected!', e);
};

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var video = document.querySelector('video');

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia(

    {
      audio: true,
      video: true
    },

    function(stream)

    {
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    },

    errorCallback);
} else {
  video.src = 'somevideo.webm';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 575%;
  color: #4A4444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1%;
  margin: 45% 0;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 275%;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1
}


}

/*---Start Parallex---*/
.parallax {
  float: left;
  border: 5px groove;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/parallax-2.jpg') repeat fixed 100%;
  */ background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.parallax-inner {
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1> Space </h1>
<section class="parallex">
  <div class="parallex-inner">
    <h2>Space</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<h1>Space</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo issues like in your style sheet you are designing `parallax` but when you added the class to the `section` you added `parallex` correct your style sheet and it will work:

```
*{

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;

}

h1 {

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 575%;
  color: #4A4444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1%;
  margin: 45% 0;
}

h2 {

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 275%;
  color: #E5E5E5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1
}

.parallex {
  float: left;
  border: 5px groove;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/parallax-2.jpg') repeat fixed 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: auto;
}


.parallex-inner {
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;

}
```

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;

}

h1 {

text-align: center;
font-size: 575%;
color: #4A4444;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1%;
margin: 45% 0;

}

h2 {

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 275%;
    color: #E5E5E5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1
  }



/*---Start Parallex---*/

.parallex{

float: left;
border: 5px groove;
margin-left: 70px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;

background: url('http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/parallax-2.jpg') repeat fixed 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
width: 100%;

}


.parallax-inner{
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;

}
```

```html
<body>

        <h1> Space </h1>


    <section class="parallex">

        <div class="parallex-inner">

            <h2>Space</h2>

        </div>

    </section>


        <h1>Space</h1>

</body>
```

I fond some spelling errors and syntax errors.

Hope this will help you abit on the way!

Comment: thank you for that. Yes it was indeed a silly type. Also that I was debugging from a local machine instead of localhost so the changes I made had no effect. I think that caching may have been my downfall there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code using a local image file and found that the background image display but when it is passed directly(either to section or div)

```
<section style="background-image: url('049.JPG');" class="parallex">

    <div class="parallex-inner">

        <h2>Space</h2>

    </div>

</section>
```

I have to add that using the correct classes as suggested here already and removing */(surely a bug) after your background-image declaration returned me no positive result...apart from when I tried directly

Comment: yeh that worked for me as well, which is why i found it so weird. It was a typo. thanks for you input :)